# How to troubleshoot Oracle 11g performance problems?

Tags: linux, performance, oracle11g

I have recently upgraded my laptop from an older Ubuntu install on a magnetic drive, to Linux Mint 18.1 on a Solid State Drive. This upgrade involved re-installation of Oracle 11g (11.2.0.2.0), which I downloaded from the [11g Express Edition Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html).

After this upgrade, I started experiencing some serious performance issues with some PL/SQL scripts that used to run just fine on my old Oracle install. For example, the following script used to take about 20 seconds to run (and continues doing so on the old install), yet on the new install it takes about 90 seconds to run.

```
prompt p_revoke_user_perms

set serveroutput on size unlimited

declare
   -- Variables ----------------------------------------------------------------
   l_from_data varchar2(30) := upper('&1');
   l_to_application varchar2(30) := upper('&2');
   l_cmd varchar2(2000);

begin
   dbms_output.put_line('BEGIN SCRIPT');

   for obj in 
      (
      select distinct table_name from all_tab_privs
      where table_schema = l_from_data
      and grantee = l_to_application
      )
   loop
      l_cmd := 
         'REVOKE ALL ON ' 
         || l_from_data 
         || '.' 
         || '"' || obj.table_name || '"' 
         || ' FROM ' 
         || l_to_application;

      dbms_output.put_line(' before: ' || to_char(systimestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
      execute immediate l_cmd;      
      dbms_output.put_line(' after: ' || to_char(systimestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
   end loop;

   dbms_output.put_line('END SCRIPT');

end;
/
show errors

exit;
```

What are my options for diagnosing this problem? Is it possible to find out where the time is being spent? Can Oracle print some profiling information that would allow me to compare the timings between the old and the new install?

I've never had to troubleshoot such a problem with Oracle before, so I don't really know where to start with this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** After going through the steps to enable the DBMS_PROFILER, and then run it from my problem script, the problem has magically gone away. The script once again takes 20 seconds to run, as expected. I have no idea what fixed it :(.

**UPDATE 2:** After a couple of days, the problem has come back. So I'd still appreciate further troubleshooting advise.

Comment: You may verify which statement is taking time by using DBMS_PROFILER. are the memory setting same for the old and new install? data is the same too?

Comment: @PraneethGudumasu: Yes, exactly the same data. Where would I check the memory settings?

Comment: May be the machine was busy at the time the script was taking time. Perhaps, there was an Oracle Background job. Not sure though

Comment: If the problem is back then use DBMS_PROFILER again to find out which line of the program is using the most time.